# Match array based on existing array

Tags: arrays, perl

I have two arrays,

```
my @test = ('a','b','c','d','e',f,'g','h');

my @test2 = ('h','b','d');
```

I'm attempting to loop through the array `@test`, and match elements against those in `@test2,` deleting those elements that do not exist.

I have the following code:

```
foreach my $header (@test) {
        if( exists $test2[$header]){
            # do nothing
        }
        else {
            delete $test[$header];
        }
    }
```

So, I want array @test to look like this (ignore the fact this could be sorted alphabetically):

```
my @test = ('b','d','h');
```

However currently my array remains the same after the foreach loop, can anyone suggest why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're misunderstanding what 'header' is set to. It's set to (an alias of) the value in the array.

So

```
foreach my $header (@test) {
   print $header,"\n";
}
```

Will give you `a`, `b`, `c` etc.

However, then you're trying to access `$test2['a']` which isn't valid, because it should be numeric.

So actually, a good case study in why you should use `strict` and `warnings` because this would have told you the problem:

```
Argument "a" isn't numeric in array or hash lookup at 
Argument "b" isn't numeric in array or hash lookup at
```

etc.

So it's not *actually* doing anything.

You shouldn't use delete in this way either though, because you're deleting from a list whilst iterating it. That's not good, even without the fact that it's nonsense to use a letter as an array index.

You could do it like this instead though:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my @test = ('a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h');

my @test2 = ('h','b','d');

my %is_in_test2 = map { $_ => 1 } @test2; 
@test = grep { $is_in_test2{$_} } @test;

print Dumper \@test;
```

If you do want to iterate by index, you can do it like this:

```
for my $index ( 0..$#test ) {  
   print "$index => $test[$index]\n";
}
```

But I would still suggest that deleting whilst iterating isn't a great plan, because modifying a thing you're iterating it ( and aiming to resize the array) is a good way to end up with strange bugs.

So whilst you could:

```
for my $index ( 0..$#test ) {  
   print "$index => $test[$index]\n";
   delete $test[$index] if not $is_in_test2{$test[$index]};
}
print Dumper \@test;
```

What you'll end up with is:

```
$VAR1 = [
          undef,
          'b',
          undef,
          'd',
          undef,
          undef,
          undef,
          'h'
        ];
```

For the more general case there is a a [`FAQ: How do I computer the difference/intersection of two arrays`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq4.html#How-do-I-compute-the-difference-of-two-arrays%3F-How-do-I-compute-the-intersection-of-two-arrays%3F)

Comment: oh thanks, how can I access the the value out of interest?

Comment: Index values? Typically `for my $index ( 0..$#test ) { `

Answer (score 0):

```
use strict;
use warnings;


my @test = ('a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h');
my @test2 = ('h','b','d');

foreach my $header (@test) {
    foreach my $header2 (@test2) {
        if( $header eq $header2) {
            print "$header,";     #prints only existing values
        }
        else {
            #doNothing
        }
    }
}
```

**Note: This method is not feasible when you are dealing an array with huge elements.**

Comment: It's an O(N^2) algorithm, so yeah. As arrays embiggen, this will get slow.